# Robot framework: Is there a way to write dynamic test cases?

Tags: robotframework

I am pretty new to robot framework. I would like to create test cases dynamically without having a input key-value driven approach.

Found some material that suggested the following:

```
suite = TestSuite('Example suite', doc='...')
tc = TestCase('Example test')
tc.add_step(TestStep('Log', args=['Hello, world!'])
suite.add_test(tc)
```

I dont see add_step in test case class, Will continue to look around and see if there are any solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The `TestSuite` object has a `keywords` attribute which itself has a `create` method which can be used to create new keywords.

The [robot framework api documentation](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.running.html) gives this [example](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.running.html#examples):

```
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
suite.resource.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])
test.keywords.create('Set Environment Variable', args=['SKYNET', 'activated'], type='setup')
test.keywords.create('Environment Variable Should Be Set', args=['SKYNET'])
```

The above gives you the same test as if you had written it like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Should Activate Skynet
    [Tags]    smoke
    [Setup]    Set Environment Variable    SKYNET    activated
    Environment Variable Should Be Set    SKYNET
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thanks for pointing me to the documentation.

Comment: How to get the log.html and report.html after executing this?